# How do i access a hidden field in the partial from jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a hidden field in the partial view that was called from an jquery ajax

```
  $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/delete',
                method: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': data }),
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/json chartset=utf-8',
                success:function (data) {
                  //how to extract hidden field total

                },
                error: function () { }
            });
```

`delete()` action returns a partial view.

Here is the hidden field in the partial

```
@html.hidden("total", Model.Students.Count());
```

the return is a `partial` that contains the **hidden field** `total`. the `data` contains the hidden field but how do i extract it from `data`?

Comment: If you inspect the actual HTML then you it should become clear. You'll need an id or class or something to find it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phill,

@html.hidden is rendered as

```
<input type="hidden" value="My Hidden Value" />
```

If you assign some id to @html.hidden the same will be reflected in the rendered html as well.

```
<input type="hidden" value="Hello I am  Hidden Value" id="txtHidden"/>
```

Now in the main view where you have imported this partial view, you can access its value using jQuery as below

```
var myHid= $('#txtHidden').val();
//myHid will get the value = 'Hello I am Hidden Value'
```

Hope, this helps you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added a sample code to find the hidden input value that you are getting in response as HTML,Write code like this inside the success block of your ajax call.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

          //This is partial page html
           var partialHtml = "<div><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"2\"  id=\"total\"/></div>";
            alert($(partialHtml).find("#total").val());

     });
 </script>
```